# Subtract counts returned from two tables using tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables called `A` and `B`.

Table `A` contains request details such as 
`request_id`, `company_id`, and `Customer_id`.

Table B contains feedback data such as `feedback_id`, `company_id`, `status_ind`,`customer_id`, `score_total`.

I need to get the count of rows of table `B` which has corresponding `company_id` with table `A` where the `status_ind` is `1` and subtract from the count of table `A`.

Comment: Those CheckATrade queries keep coming back to haunt me - PL :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking but

```
declare @countA integer = (select count(*) from A)

declare @countB integer = 
    (select count(*) from B where 
     exists(select * from A where A.company_id = B.company_id AND A.status_ind = 1)

declare @difference integer = @countA - @countB
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use a sql stored procedure or function.

Comment: Yeah you could. But bit struggling with the query it self.

Comment: You do not need a stored procedure or function. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure. But i understood it like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A WHERE company_id NOT IN (SELECT company_id FROM B WHERE status_ind = 1)
```

I edited it, i thought first that status_ind is in table A not in B

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your problem can be rephrased like this: *count rows of `A` that have no matches with the `status_ind = 1` rows of `B`*.

Well, just use an anti-join, like this, for instance:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.company_id = B.company_id AND B.status_ind = 1
WHERE B.company_id IS NULL
```